# Powershell window does not open in same position where I last closed it

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, window-manager

If I open up a powershell window from the start menu and move it around, when I close it and start it up again, the Powershell window starts in the same position that it started in last time, as opposed to in the position that I closed it in. If I repeat the same thing with notepad, notepad opens in the same position that I closed it in.

Can anybody explain this behavior to me? How can I change where a PowerShell window will open next time?

Comment: Powershell terminal properties, which @DavidPostill just answered with, with another alternative being [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), which allows you to fully customize the terminal in its entirety.

Comment: Check if this can help with you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231739/set-the-position-of-powershell-window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How can I change where a PowerShell window will open next time?

- Open PowerShell
- Click on the PowerShell icon at the left end of the title bar
- Click Defaults
- Click Layout
- Enter Top and Left
- Click OK

  > [image]
- Click Properties
- Click Layout
- Enter Top and Left
- Click OK

  > [image]
- Restart PowerShell